# Remote Invoke-Command Powershell Stop-WebAppPool No Longer Working After Powershell 5 Upgrade

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.0

We have a PowerShell script that takes down a remote app pool via the following commands:

```
$appPoolName = "myAppPool"
$server = "myserver.domain.com"

$stopAppPoolScript = {param($appPoolname); Import-Module WebAdministration; Stop-WebAppPool -Name $appPoolName;}
#remotely execute script to stop the app pool
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -scriptBlock $stopAppPoolScript -ArgumentList $appPoolname

#sleep for 10 seconds
Start-Sleep -s 10

#print out the status of the app pool
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -scriptBlock $checkAppPoolStatusScript -ArgumentList $appPoolname
#always says "Started"
```

This script has worked for a very long time when the build server that is issuing the command is on PowerShell 4 and the remote server is on PowerShell version 2. However, this weekend I upgraded the build server to Windows Management Framework 5 (and Powershell 5) and the Stop-WebAppPool command stopped working when ran remotely via Invoke-Command via our build server. I confirmed that from my local machine which is also on PowerShell 5 I also cannot issue this command. However, from any machine that is on Powershell 4 I CAN issue this command to the remote server and it works.

Other things I've tried that may be pertinent:
* If I establish a remote PowerShell session and issue the command interactively it works fine.
* I can run the command to check the app pool status and it works fine: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -scriptBlock $checkAppPoolStatusScript -ArgumentList $appPoolname`
* Establishing a session and then calling `Invoke-Command -Session $mySession...` didn't help either. It still does not stop the app pool.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm wondering if there's an issue with Powershell 5 issuing remote commands to PowerShell 2... or maybe something related to security changed when installing Windows Management Framework 5... or... who knows.

Comment: Installing Windows Management Framework / PowerShell 4 on the target server solved the problem -- although it doesn't really answer the question of why does this happen and is there a quick fix.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to guide you without an error.  Trap the error and write it out so we know what's wrong.

Comment: @Colyn1337 There are no errors whatsoever that I can see. I even checked the event logs on the server and there are no issues. :(

Comment: You have to trap them.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a configuration to the Invoke-Command cmdlet to have it use Powershell 2.

`Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name PS2 -PSVersion 2.0
Invoke-Command -ConfigurationName PS2 -ComputerName $env:computername -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion}`

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ESOK.png)